# Avoiding (beginners') allocation mistakes in this sequence of vector functions in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-management, struct

Context: I've decided to re-write my 3D graphics script, which evolved in Python, to C for speed. This involves me learning C. The part of the program in question caches normals information about a 3D mesh.

There are 3 vector operations called in sequence here (pretty standard: vector subtraction to get edge vector, cross product and average), which I would like to be as fast as possible, so I'm trying to avoid storing anything needlessly on the heap...and copying my structs too many times. However, I also am aware that if I return pointers I'll point to mem space which isn't valid any more.

This how I would try to write all three functions (generally speaking: struct copy in, struct copy out, rather than pointers).

```
typedef struct vector vector;
struct vector{
    double x,y,z;
};

vector vect(vector a, vector b){
    vector res;
    res.x = b.x - a.x; 
    res.y = b.y - a.y;
    res.z = b.z - a.z;
    return res;
}

vector cross(vector a, vector b){
    vector res;
    res.x = a.y*b.z - a.z*b.y;
    res.y = a.z*b.x - a.x*b.z;
    res.z = a.x*b.y - a.y*b.x;
    return res;
}

vector avg (vector a, vector b){
    vector res;
    res.x = (a.x + b.x)/2;
    res.y = (a.y + b.y)/2;
    res.z = (a.z + b.z)/2;
    return res;
}
```

And this is how it's called:

```
m->Tpolynormals[i] = avg(cross( vect(*p->verts[0], *p->verts[1]),
                                vect(*p->verts[1], *p->verts[2]) ),
                         cross( vect(*p->verts[2], *p->verts[3]),
                                vect(*p->verts[3], *p->verts[0]) )
                        );
```

Is this fairly efficient or is there a faster way to do it? I know I can experiment and "make it work", but at this point I'd like to make sure the foundations are solid. - Thanks

Edit: added my struct definition above, as someone obviously pointed out, duh. The coordinates are doubles (it's what my 3D package outputs) and system is 64-bit.

Comment: Don't afraid of pointers. Just learn to use them properly. To return a result you can just add a destination parameter to you functions which will get populated. Passing and returning pointers is more efficient than passing and returning structs.

Comment: Why are you asking a question about (memory) allocation and then don't post a single line that has anything to do with the alleged topic?

Comment: @EOF Because I think it does. Passing in and returning structs from function to function is memory usage as copies of them get created. Passing pointers is memory usage because you have to track where it is pointing. If you have a suggestion for a more accurate title, please write it.

Comment: It looks like your code works, you just want someone to review it and improve it.  I recommend CodeReview.StackExchange.com for this.

Comment: It is not impossible that, when *inlined*, this code will perform reasonably.

Comment: Platform dependent - which I have not seen stated.  1) If the processor does not have native support for `a.y*b.z` math, I would be inclined to pass all by value.  OTOH, with native `a.y*b.z` support, pass structures by their address. 2) Can parallel  code paths be considered?

Comment: This should probably be on CodeReview (just saying). "Is there a better/faster way" can generate too many answers for SO

Comment: You've not specified the type of the coordinates of the vector.  If the type is `short` and you're on a 64-bit machine, then passing pointers instead of structures might cause more data to be passed (8 bytes for the pointer vs 6 for the vector), plus adding to the access time with the dereferencing.  Even if the type is `double`, then you're still passing 6 8-byte values vs 2 8-byte pointers.  It isn't clear cut which approach is best — measurement on relevant platforms is the only way to find out what works best.  Note that making the functions `inline` may be helpful (`static inline …`).

Comment: As a side note, `vector` is probably one of the worst identifier names to use in any programming context. Because it can refer to arrays and it can refer to mathematical vectors. In case of the former, it can also refer to the very badly named, but very frequently used C++ container called `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Avoiding (beginners') allocation mistakes" vs. "I would like to be as fast as possible,"

Which is more important?

If code needs to be as fast as possible, try a number of approaches and profile them to see what works best for you.  You will make mistakes.

The sizeof `vector` is in the border region of providing a general answer to what is best, passing `vector` by value or its address.  Best to try both

1) Pass `vector` by value.  OP seems to understand that well.

```
vector vect(vector a, vector b){
    vector res;
    res.x = b.x - a.x; 
    res.y = b.y - a.y;
    res.z = b.z - a.z;
    return res;
}
```

2) Pass `vector` by its address.  Create intermediate result locations.  This seems to be the part OP is uncertain.

```
void V_vect(vector *res, const vector *a, const vector *b){
    res->x = b->x - a->x; 
    res->y = b->y - a->y;
    res->z = b->z - a->z;
}

// usage example
vector res1;
vector res2;
V_vect(&res1, p->verts[0], p->verts[1]);
V_vect(&res2, p->verts[1], p->verts[2]);
vector res3;
V_cross(&res3, &res1, &res2);

V_vect(&res1, p->verts[2], p->verts[3]);
V_vect(&res2, p->verts[3], p->verts[0]);
vector res4;
V_cross(&res4, &res1, &res2);

V_avg(&m->Tpolynormals[i], &res3, &res4);
```

---

In particular, recommend to avoid re-using memory in the same call as in below.  That could be a rookie mistake, both in function and code performance.

```
V_cross(&res2, &res1, &res2);
```

A way to *speed* things when passing the address is to use `restrict`.  This allows a compiler to know the calling code is using pointers to areas that do not overlap.   This allows for certain compiler optimizations.

```
void V_vect(vector * restrict res, const vector * restrict a, const vector * restrict b){
    res->x = b->x - a->x; 
    res->y = b->y - a->y;
    res->z = b->z - a->z;
}
```

With `restrict` the 1st below call is undefined behavior as it overlaps the `vector`s.

```
// V_cross(&res2, &res1, &res2);  // bad
V_cross(&res4, &res1, &res2);  // good
```

---

Try various approaches (including [@Jonathan Leffler compound literal idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129062/avoiding-beginners-allocation-mistakes-in-this-sequence-of-vector-functions-i/38131179#comment63693694_38131179) and [@Jonathan Leffler inline idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129062/avoiding-beginners-allocation-mistakes-in-this-sequence-of-vector-functions-i/38131179#comment63693976_38129062)) and uses what works well for you.

Comment: Any idea how the code size/speed of code using C99 compound literals and designated initializers compares with the alternatives?  For example,  `vector vect(vector a, vector b){ return (vector){ .x = b.x - a.x, .y = b.y - a.y, .z = b.z - a.z }; }`.  Gut feel: the optimizer will likely generate very similar code for both this and the pass/return-by-value code, so there's not much, if any, benefit to the more compact but opaque notation.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  Agree your idea is worth trying - although I doubt major differences using compound literals.  Certainly none of the methods are orders of magnitude faster than the other.  Its depends highly on the compiler/platform.

Comment: I'd mention a 3rd way - but leave as a comment to avoid clutter. Use `vector * vect(vector *res, const vector *a, const vector *b){ ... return res; }` and `avg(&y,cross(&res3, vect(&res1, &v0,&v1), vect(&res2, &v1,&v2), cross(&res6, vect(&res4, &v2,&v3), vect(&res5, &v3,&v0)))` if you really want to chain code.

Comment: `restrict` will prevent you from using code such as `V_vect(x, x, y)` though. Seems like a sound use case? All operations to the internal variables of "x" are properly sequenced inside the function. Also, if we are to use micro-optimizations like these, `inline` may be much more efficient.

Comment: @Lundin   Agree `inline`, (with or without `restrict`)  is another attribute that could be used to find what works best for OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to minimize the amount of data being copied around, you can pass in pointers to the input and output parameters.  That would mean however that you can't chain function calls together as you do above, and it means you'd need to have temp variables to hold the result of each call.

For example:

```
void vect(vector *a, vector *b, vector *res){
    res->x = b->x - a->x; 
    res->y = b->y - a->y;
    res->z = b->z - a->z;
}

// similarly for the other two
```

Then to call them:

```
vector vect1, vect2, vect3, vect4, cross1, cross2;
vect(p->verts[0], p->verts[1], &vect1);
vect(p->verts[1], p->verts[2], &vect2);
vect(p->verts[2], p->verts[3], &vect3);
vect(p->verts[3], p->verts[0], &vect4);
cross(&vect1, &vect2, &cross1);
cross(&vect3, &vect4, &cross2);
avg(&cross1, &cross2, &m->Tpolynormals[i]);
```